# Get Request HttpUrlConnection - Incorrect response

Tags: android, get, httpurlconnection

I am working on an Android App, App is using GET Request to connect with server.
The code I have written to connect with server is working perfectly on many devices.
But its not giving good response on `LENOVO` YOGA TAB3, It returns `Html` tags instead of `JSON` text, Firstly I was confused that there may be some issue in the `API` URL but I checked URL using browser, Its returning good response so I am sure URL is correct.

Here are API URL and its response :

**API URL**

```
[http://www.xyz.in/xyzapi/?building=on&address=Assotech Sandal Suites, Sector 135, Noida, Uttar Pradesh 201304, India&bill_amount=12500&type=R&fullstatename=Uttar Pradesh&lat=28.496171099999998&lng=77.4027049&state=UP&country=IN&district=Gautam Buddha Nagar&sublocality=Sector 135&calc-sess=59d4beba305f3&netmetering=1][1]
```

**Response on Many Android Phones:**

```
{"lifetimesaving":"25.0 Lacs","proposed_pv_capacity":10,"billWithSolar":3872,"bill_amount":"12500","sanction":10,"project_cost":"6.0 Lacs","return_oninevstment":"20.8","roi_image":"solar_score6_6.png","treeadded":"346 ","treeofftheroad":"9 "}
```

**Response on Lenovo Yoga Tab3:**

```
<head/><style>.personal-details h2{font-size:34px}.netmetering-tgle{position:absolute;left:0;right:0;bottom:5px;width:211px}.netmetering-tgle .wnm{float:left;position:relative;padding:0 10px 0 0;min-width:130px;text-align:center}.netmetering-tgle .wnm a{color:#c97511;background:none}#radioBtn .btn{border:1px solid transparent;border-radius:0!important;font-family:"Din-Bold"}#radioBtn .notActive{color:#c97511;background-color:#e0e1e2;padding:2px 0;width:38px;background-size:100% 100%;border-color:transparent;font-family:"Din-Bold";border-radius:5px}#radioBtn .active{color:#fff;background-color:#addc6f;border-color:transparent;padding:2px 5px;width:38px;cursor:auto;pointer-events:none;border-radius:5px;box-shadow:inset 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,.8)}#radioBtn .notActive[data-
```

So response is **incorrect** on Yoga Tab3.

**Here is the code I am using to connect with Server :**

```
    public static String connectToServerUsingGETMethod(String API_COMPLETE_URL){

    URL url;
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    try {
        url = new URL(API_COMPLETE_URL);

        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();

        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(in);

        String line = "";
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }
        //get the string version of the response data
        return sb.toString();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (urlConnection != null) {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
    }

    return "";
}
```

Suggest me If I can add something in this code so that it can work on Yoga Tab 3 too.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should set static content type when making request to make sure the response sent back is JSON. Similarly, it looks like below:

```
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
```

Hope it works for you.

Comment: Tried with this, Was giving same response.

Comment: Instead of using `Content-Type: application/json`, change to `Accept: application/json`. May it work for you?

Comment: This is a get request, so we can not set Accept , Accept is for POST request.